# Teamcity auto build dynamic named branch

Tags: continuous-integration, devops, teamcity

Currently having issues with team city build triggers on release branches.

Following gitflow convention we currently branch off develop and create a release branch, e.g release/1.0.0

What I am trying to do is when this branch is created/pushed too have team city run a build automatically.

I have created a VCS root specifically for the release branch and have it set up like:

[image: VCS Root Details]

I have my branch filter like this:

[image: Branch filter]

And added a VCS Trigger that looks like this:

[image: Trigger]

Or in code

```
vcs {
    quietPeriodMode = VcsTrigger.QuietPeriodMode.USE_DEFAULT
    branchFilter = """
        +:release/*|<default>
        -:*
    """.trimIndent()
}
```

As you can see I need to select the branch

[image: Build]

What I ideally want is for team city to CI where the trigger will auto start the build for each release branch.

Where have I gone wrong, or am missing?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `|` in `+:release/*|<default>` is a valid syntax.

You should instead use

```
+:release/*
+:<default>
```